# Remove from a list that has a list within it based on integer list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that basically look like this...

```
public class Area
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCodeAdresses> ListOfIncludedDestinations { get; set; }
}

public class ZipCodeAdresses
{
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public List<Person> AdressList { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string MottagarNamn { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}




var intListToRemove = new List<int>(){2,3};
var list = new List<Area>();

var subList = new List<ZipCodeAdresses>();
var personList = new List<Person>
{
     new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 1"}, 
     new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 2"}
};
subList.Add(new ZipCodeAdresses(){AdressList = personList , AreaId = 1});

personList = new List<Person>
{
    new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 3"},
    new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 4"}
};
subList.Add(new ZipCodeAdresses() { AdressList = personList, AreaId = 2 });
list.Add(new Area(){Name = "List A", ListOfIncludedDestinations = subList});


subList = new List<ZipCodeAdresses>();
personList = new List<Person>
{
    new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 5"},
    new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 6"}
};
subList.Add(new ZipCodeAdresses() { AdressList = personList, AreaId = 3 });

personList = new List<Person>
{
     new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 7"},
     new Person() {MottagarNamn = "User 8"}
};
subList.Add(new ZipCodeAdresses() { AdressList = personList, AreaId = 4 });

list.Add(new Area() { Name = "List B", ListOfIncludedDestinations = subList });
```

I need to be able to remove from the list `ListOfIncludedDestinations` where AreaId is equal to any integer in `intListToRemove` which in this example is 2 and 3?

Comment: This doesn't compile (`Person` class doesn't have a property called `MottagarNamn`)

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` contains a method [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0), that removes all entries that fulfill a certain condition. In your case it is:

```
foreach(var entry in list)
        {
            entry.ListOfIncludedDestinations.RemoveAll(x => intListToRemove.Contains(x.AreaId));
        }
```

This loops through your `list`, and for every entry it removes all entries in `ListOfIncludedDestinations` that have an `AreadId` which is in `intListToRemove`.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ialnPb

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar `List.ForEach` is not LINQ. Nor do lambdas make it so. Actually **nothing** in your comment is LINQ since `Contains` and `RemoveAll` are also List methods pre-dating language integrated queries

Answer (score 0):

You should add this sample code to remove them from the list :

```
foreach (var i in list)
                i.ListOfIncludedDestinations.RemoveAll(o => intListToRemove.Contains(o.AreaId));
```